# How to minimize the flooding of RREQ packet in AODV if an intermediate node has replied the source with the path?

Tags: networking

Suppose we have a condition in AODV protocol
 
*RREQ(route request) packet in AODV(MANET protocol) goes on moving to the destination even if a node at TTL=1 has replied for the route request.
For example,
n1,n2 and n3 are 3 nodes at TTL=1 and n2 replies to source S but n1 and n3 have rebroadcasted the RREQ packet towards destination D which would perhaps create unnecessary flooding in the network .* 
Now I thought a naive solution to minimize this flooding that n2 will also broadcast another packet containing information that it has replied to the RREQ for S to D probably using something like a  higher Destination sequence number in it or containing the same Broadcast ID as the RREQ. But what it will do is create another chance of flooding . So,are there any possible ways by which we could minimize this problem in a more effective manner?
**NOTE:AODV is a reactive routing protocol in Mobile Ad-Hoc network systems which rely on table routing .**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a research topic. There are several solutions provided for the same. On of the efficient solution is provided as:
Source node starts broadcasting for the first time with a small TTL value of 1. This RREQ reaches adjacent nodes, they checks weather they contain an updated route for the destination. Those having an updated route for the destination replies with RREP and rest of the nodes can't rebroadcast because TTL is expired. If no one has the route, the RREQ is rebroadcasted by source with one increased value of TTL=2. This way, RREQ packet is rebroadcasted only when the nodes do not have path for the destination.
This method also increases flooding of RREQ packets but it is an optimization problem, still it is one of the good method to solve this problem.
Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The Condition Of node in Aodv protocol is just check the receiving packet type, if its RREQ means just forward to all of its neighbours .if u want to minimize RREQ u can add your condition in Recvpacket() functions.better is u can use number of hops to create a new condition.